# Confusion related to posterior gaussian process

Tags: gaussian-process

I was reading this `[paper][1]` related to sparse online gaussian processes. However, I didn't get how the denominator in the equation 1 was derived?[image]

It was supposed to be P(D). I didn't get how the denominator was obtained. Further, the paper is saying that the posterior may not be gaussian. I don't know why it is so?

Comment: To the first question: $P(D)$, the likelihood of the data, is equivalent to the average of the likelihood wrt the prior through the law of total probability. The analogue in a simpler parametric expression is $P(D) = \int p(D, \theta) d\theta = \int P(D \mid \theta) p(\theta) d\theta = E_\theta[P(D \mid \theta)]$.

Comment: @Matthew, the paper is saying that the posterior may not be gaussian. Why?